# Correct way to bind parameters using MySQL "IN" syntax in Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

Ok, I'm using `Yii2` and I'm familiar with preparing/binding data when using mysql queries, such as:

```
$sql = $this->db->createCommand("UPDATE some_table SET something='foo' WHERE some_id=:some_id");
$sql->bindValue(':some_id', $some_id);
```

But what about when the value *may* contain multiple values, such as when using the `MySQL` syntax `IN`?

For example:

```
$sql = $this->db->createCommand("UPDATE some_table SET something='foo' WHERE some_id IN (:parents)");
$sql->bindValue(':parents', $parents);
```

Now as I understand the above would only work well if the `$parents` var only had *one* value; but if it had multiple values such as `1,2,3` then you would end up with something like `'1,2,3'` when you really want `'1','2','3'` OR `1,2,3`.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: @saty instead of giving advice on topics you don't know about, do read the manual before you type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Comment: This is in fact a duplicate of my problem. Thanks Brett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
$parents_safe = '';
$parents_sep = explode(',', $parents);

foreach ($parents_sep as $parent) {
    $parents_safe .= $this->db->quoteValue($parent) . ',';
}

$parents_safe = rtrim($parents_safe, ',');
```

Where `$this->db` is an instance of `Yii::$app->db`.

Answer (score 9):

I've found this solution

```
$params = [];
$sql = \Yii::$app->db->getQueryBuilder()->buildCondition(['IN', 'some_id', $ids], $params);
//$sql = some_id NOT IN (:qp0, :qp1, :qp2)
//$params = [':qp0'=>1, ':qp1'=>2, ':qp2'=>3]
$this->db->createCommand("UPDATE some_table SET something='foo' WHERE $sql", $params);
```

Comment: Deprecated since 2.0.14. Is not used, will be dropped in 2.1.0. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-querybuilder#$conditionBuilders-detail

Answer (score 8):

You can just use Yii's QueryBuilder functions and everything will be handled automatically. Try this:

```
$params = [];
$sql = \Yii::$app->db->getQueryBuilder()->update('some_table', ['something' => 'foo'], ['some_id' => [1, 2, 3]], $params);
```

The result:

```
string(78) "UPDATE `some_table` SET `something`=:qp0 WHERE `some_id` IN (:qp1, :qp2, :qp3)"
array(4) { [":qp0"]=> string(3) "foo" [":qp1"]=> int(1) [":qp2"]=> int(2) [":qp3"]=> int(3) }
```

Comment: What if I need to implement criteria like some_id NOT IN (1, 2, 3) AND some_field = 2

Comment: @Rjazhenka something like `['and', ['not', ['some_id' => [1, 2, 3]]], ['some_field' => 2]]`. See specification http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where()-detail

Answer (score 4):

Yii2's DB functions are based on `PDO`.
According to the manual of [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) there's no support of value from `Array` type. (Third parameter - `data_type`).

The solution is to create a string prior to the query, which fits to your `IN` clause and bind it as a string.

Something like:

```
$parents = "1,2,3";
/*
Or in case you already have an array of the desirable ids:
$parents_array = array(1,2,3);
$parents = implode(",",$parents_array);
*/

$sql = $this->db->createCommand("UPDATE some_table SET something='foo' WHERE some_id IN (:parents)");
$sql->bindValue(':parents', $parents);
```

**Edit**

It seems that the placeholder being replaced by the imploded array as a one string value `'1,2,3'` instead of `'1','2','3'` (since it's a single placeholder).

In order to solve this issue, i'll suggest using the multiple `?` placeholders.
So instead of having `IN (:parents)` you would have `IN (?, ?, ?, ? ,....)`, and since we already have an arranged array - we can use `count($array)` to know how much placeholders we need to put.

```
//$parents = array(1,2,3);
$placeholders = str_repeat('?,', count($parents) - 1). '?';
$sql = $this->db->createCommand("UPDATE some_table SET something='foo' WHERE some_id IN (".$placeholders.")");

foreach($parents as $i => $parent){
 $sql->bindValue($i+1, $parent);  
}
```

Please notice the passed value of the first parameter of bindValue;
The reason it's `$i+1` and not `$i` mentioned in the manual:

> For a prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will
>   be the **1-indexed position** of the parameter.

For further information and alternative solutions, look at the following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/920523/998096

Comment: Wouldn't that just end up with the value being tried as `'1,2,3'`?

Comment: @Brett it will be `1,2,3` not `'1,2,3'` and the query will work

Comment: @Bsienn Doesn't binding with `bindValue` cause the value to be quoted though?

Comment: @OfirBaruch Well, I guess this would solve the issue with *trusted data*, but it wouldn't really be advisable to use this method if using user provided data within the `IN`; I guess I was more looking for a more robust solution and not just one for this particular situation.

Comment: Well I just tested and I was right, using this method ended up with `'1,2,3'` and didn't work correctly.

Comment: I have another idea - using the `?` placeholders. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If data is **TRUSTED**, this one solution works pretty good:

```
$db = Yii::$app->db;
$ids = "'" . implode("','", $ids_array) . "'";
$result = $db->createCommand("
    UPDATE some_table SET something='foo' WHERE some_id IN ($ids)
")->queryColumn();
```

Comment: I agree to just use the raw data if you just recovered it from a trusted location.

Comment: It will not work  if data contains `'` or `\` at the end of string. I would not use this for anything except integers.

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs a solution for **Yii1**:

```php
$db = \Yii::app()->db;

$inCondition = $db
    ->getCommandBuilder()
    ->createInCondition('some_table', 'some_id', $parents);

$command = $db
    ->createCommand("UPDATE some_table SET something = :foo WHERE $inCondition");

$command->bindValue(':foo', 'foo');
$command->execute();
```

Answer (score -5):

Just do

```
$parents = implode("','", $parrent_array);
$sql->bindValue(':parents', $parents);
```

Should probably do the trick.

Comment: For that to work it would rely on the values being like `'1','2','3'`.

Comment: Thats insecure imagine somebody passes e.g. `"don't panik"` in $parant_array, this would crash your query and opens the door for sql injections